# RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QPlainTextEdit has been deleted

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to launch a widget from menuBar, then pop open a TextEdit dialog when the user clicks a button. This all works fine, however, if I were to close out of the widget and re-launch the widget again, I randomly runs into the 'RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QPlainTextEdit has been deleted'.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mydirectory", line 373, in startClicked
    self.runF.logger.info('Initializing...')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1332, in info
    self._log(INFO, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1468, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1478, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1540, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 854, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "mydirectory", line 19, in emit
    self.widget.appendPlainText(self.format(record))
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QPlainTextEdit has been deleted
```

I cannot figure out why this is an issue as I am creating a new instance of the TextEdit dialog during my widget init.

Below is my trimmed down code, but I can't seem to reproduce this issue-

mainTest.py

```
from PyQt5 import  QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import logging
import test1


class mainTest(QMenuBar):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        logging.basicConfig(filename=fr'testuser_debug.log', level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        self.setWindowState(self.windowState() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimized | QtCore.Qt.WindowActive | Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
        self.setWindowTitle('test')
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.viewMenu = self.addMenu('&Views')
        self.viewSubMenu = QMenu(self.viewMenu)
        self.viewSubMenu.setTitle('&Tools')
        self.testTool = QAction("&test Tool", self)
        self.viewSubMenu.addAction(self.testTool)
        self.viewMenu.addAction(self.viewSubMenu.menuAction())
        self.testTool.triggered.connect(self.testToolPopup)
        self.setFixedHeight(self.sizeHint().height())
        self.resize(500, self.height())

    def testToolPopup(self):
        try:
            self.third_screen.setWindowState(
                self.windowState() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimized | QtCore.Qt.WindowActive)
            self.third_screen.activateWindow()
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            self.third_screen = test1.test1GUI(self)
            self.third_screen.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = mainTest()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

test1.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import logging
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class QPlainTextEditLogger(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.widget = QPlainTextEdit(parent)
        self.widget.setReadOnly(True)

    def emit(self, record):
        self.widget.appendPlainText(self.format(record))


class emitLogging(QDialog, QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.logTextBox = QPlainTextEditLogger(self)
        self.logTextBox.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(message)s'))
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('auction')
        self.logger.addHandler(self.logTextBox)
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        self.runButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.runButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.runButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.runButton.setText("Run")
        layout.addWidget(self.logTextBox.widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.runButton)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        try:
            self.parent.setEnabled(True)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(e)
            print(e)

class test1GUI(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        try:
            self.parent = parent
            self.setWindowTitle("test1 Tool")
            self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
            self.runF = emitLogging(self)

            self.genButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
            self.genButton.setText("Generate")
            self.genButton.clicked.connect(self.genClicked)

            self.tda = TDA(self)
            self.tda.status.connect(self.logggin)

            self.vboxB = QVBoxLayout()
            self.vboxB.addWidget(self.genButton)
            self.setLayout(self.vboxB)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            logging.error(e)

    def genClicked(self):
        try:
            self.setEnabled(False)
            self.runF.setEnabled(True)
            self.runF.logTextBox.widget.clear()
            self.tda._process_call()
            self.runF.show()
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def logggin(self, txt):
        try:
            self.runF.logger.info(txt)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

class TDA(QObject):

    status = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent

    def _process_call(self):
        self.status.emit('test....')
        print('here')
```

Comment: Well, you did add `self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)`...

Comment: @musicamante that should be fine no? it will clean up the widget when i close out of it, then re-initiate via self.third_screen = test1.test1GUI(self)

Comment: @Ken The `try/except` block in `testToolPopup` ensures that a new instance is only created when `self` does not already have a `'third_screen'` attribute. Closing the dialog will delete the underlying C++ object, but the Python wrapper will be left behind. Qt obviously knows nothing about Python, so the `self.third_screen` attribute *will not be deleted*. When `testToolPopup` is called again, your code tries to call `self.third_screen.setWindowState(...)`, and since this is an inherited Qt method, a runtime-error will be raised (because the underlying C++ object no longer exists).

Answer (score 0):

The `WA_DeleteOnClose` attribute only deletes the widget, not its python reference. The result is that when you call `testToolPopup` again, accessing `self.third_screen` will not raise an `AttributeError` exception (the object exists), but will raise a `RuntimeError` one because the wrapped object has been destroyed by the above setting and it's not possible to access its Qt attributes and functions.

Remember that Qt is a *binding*, every python object used to refer to a Qt object is actually a wrapper around the *actual* C++ object:

- a python object representing a Qt object can get deleted, and the Qt object will still exist; this is the case of `layout` in `emitLogging`: the python object is garbage collected after the `__init__`, but the actual QLayout exists as its ownership belongs to the widget, and can be accessed again from python using `layout = self.layout()`;
- a Qt object can get destroyed, and the python object referring to it will still exist until manually `del`eted or garbage collected;

The latter is exactly your case, as the wrapped QWidget is destroyed after being closed, even though `self.third_screen` still exists. Since the wrapped object is destroyed, PyQt cannot properly access its attributes, like `setWindowState` or `activateWindow`.

In your case, a possibility is to connect to the [`destroyed`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#destroyed) signal and delete the python reference too:

```
    def testToolPopup(self):
        # ...
        except Exception as e:
            # ...
            self.third_screen.destroyed.connect(self.third_destroyed)

    def third_destroyed(self):
        del self.third_screen
```

Comment: I see what you mean, and agreed that once I close the widget and try to re-open it, the error i get is the RuntimeError. However, I am under the impression that the exception is handled by reassigning the  python object self.third_screen to a new widget instance via ```self.third_screen = test1.test1GUI(self)```, doesnt this effectively set the python object to a new Qt object? Similar to say 
```x=1```
```x=2```
x is now 2.

Comment: @Ken we can only give answers based on the code you provide. The exception is managed, and I only can point out why it's raised. If you get a "random error" it means that the code you provided can *not* reproduce the issue. So you either find what's wrong with your original code, or you try to find a way to actually reproduce it and provide that MRE to us.